# Embedded select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I basically am trying to make a little web platform that filters football club stats have this structure

```
Countries(countryId, country Name)
FootballClubs(clubId, countryId, clubName)
Players(playerID, playerName, native CountryId, Birthdate)
PlayersInClubs(playerId, clubId, startDate, endDate, playerNumber)
```

I need to find all the clubs that had English and Spanish players in it that wore the 25th number after the year 2000

basically I need to get the specific Country ID's for England and Spain that wore the playerNumber=25 after startDate 2000

I can write all those things separately but I'm trying to figure out how embedded statements work and am failing to make a working thing

```
SELECT clubName
FROM FootballClubs, PlayersInClubs
WHERE
  PlayersInClubs.playerID=Players.playerID 
  
  (Select playerNumber
  From Players
  Where
  playerNumber=25 AND startDate>DATEPART(year, '2000/01/01') 
)
```

pretty much what I have

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EXISTS` to find if there were any `PlayersInClubs` for a given `FootballClub` after `'20000101'`. You need an `EXISTS` because there may be more than one row returned, and a `JOIN` would end up multiplying rows.

And to check the `Countries` you can simply join it.

```sql
SELECT fc.*
FROM FootballClubs fc
JOIN Countries c ON c.countryId = fc.countryId
    AND c.countryName IN ('England', 'Spain')
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM PlayersInClubs pic
    WHERE pic.clubId = c.clubId  -- join condition
      AND pic.startDate >= '20000101'
)
```